Getting a value to appear on multiple lines
I am trying to write SQL code to get a value that appears on one row to appear on all rows that contain a similar value. Below I have an example of what I currently have but need a way to get the "Batch Status" column to match for all rows under the same Batch ID



Batch ID
Test ID
Status
Batch Status




267
174
Success
NULL


267
175
Success
NULL


267
176
Fail
FAIL


268
177
Success
NULL


268
178
Success
NULL


268
179
Success
SUCCESS



What I need it to look like:



Batch ID
Test ID
Status
Batch Status




267
174
Success
FAIL


267
175
Success
FAIL


267
176
Fail
FAIL


268
177
Success
SUCCESS


268
178
Success
SUCCESS


268
179
Success
SUCCESS




which RDBMS you are using ? and how is rekated to power bi ?

Here is some SQL that uses a CTE (I am assuming you are using sql server given your powerbi tag):
    WITH BatchStatus AS (
    SELECT
        [Batch ID],
        CASE 
            WHEN MAX([Batch Status]) = 'FAIL' THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN MAX([Batch Status]) = 'SUCCESS' THEN 'SUCCESS'
            ELSE NULL
        END AS NewBatchStatus
    FROM BatchDetails
    GROUP BY [Batch ID]
)
SELECT
    bd.[Batch ID],
    bd.[Test ID],
    bd.[Status],
    bs.NewBatchStatus AS [Batch Status]
FROM BatchDetails bd
JOIN BatchStatus bs
ON bd.[Batch ID] = bs.[Batch ID];

Assumptions:

Sql Server syntax
[Batch Status] only has SUCCESS, FAIL and NULL


This query in SQL Server responds to the output shown in the example.
A CTE table was used to obtain the last test for each row, then the status of the last test was searched for each row
Solution
with batch_last_test as
(
    select [Batch ID], MAX([Test ID]) as [Test ID]
    from [dbo].[batchtable]
    group by [Batch ID]
)
SELECT [Row Batch].[Batch ID]
      ,[Row Batch].[Test ID]
      ,[Row Batch].[Status]
      ,[Last Batch].Status as [Batch Status]
  FROM [dbo].[batchtable] as [Row Batch]
  inner join batch_last_test
    on batch_last_test.[Batch ID] = [Row Batch].[Batch ID]
  inner join [dbo].[batchtable] as [Last Batch]
    on  batch_last_test.[Batch ID] = [Last Batch].[Batch ID]
    and batch_last_test.[Test ID] = [Last Batch].[Test ID]

Output
Batch ID    Test ID Status  Batch Status
267         174     Success Fail
267         175     Success Fail
267         176     Fail    Fail
268         177     Success Success
268         178     Success Success
268         179     Success Success


Use a window function, e.g. MAX() to get each BatchID's only/max BatchStatus value.
select BatchID, TestID, Status,
       MAX(BatchStatus) over (partition by BatchID) as BatchStatus
from batchtable

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/2cmdtuhx
